# What is wrong with my NgFor? Only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, frontend, ngfor

I have been working on a project with Angular. But my project doesn't work like it should.
I get the error "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." in the console of my page.

On my page I get the "This works" but that's it. Meanwhile I should also see the 'soort' of my 'dier'.

In my html:

```
    <p>This works</p>
    <div
    class="dier"
    *ngFor="let dier of dieren$"> 
    <p>{{dier.soort}}</p>
   </div>
```

The component (without imports and @Component):

```
   export class DierListComponent implements OnInit {
  private _fetchdieren$: Observable<Dier[]>; // = this._dierDataService.dieren$;
  public errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(private _dierDataService: DierDataService) {
   }

  get dieren$(): Observable<Dier[]>{
   return this._fetchdieren$;
  }

  addNiewDier(dier){
    this._dierDataService.addNewDier(dier); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._fetchdieren$ = this._dierDataService.dieren$.pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        this.errorMessage = err;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And the dataservice (without imports, @injectable and some (unimportant methods):

```
export class DierDataService {
  private _dieren$ = new BehaviorSubject<Dier[]>([]);
  private _dieren: Dier[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.dieren$.subscribe((dieren: Dier[]) => {
      this._dieren = dieren;
      this._dieren$.next(this._dieren);
    });
  }
 /* get allDieren$(): Observable<Dier[]> {
    return this._dieren$;
  }*/

  get dieren$(): Observable<Dier[]>{ 
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/Dieren`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      tap(console.log),
      map(
        (list: any[]): Dier[] => list.map(Dier.fromJSON)              
      )
    );
  }

  handleError(err: any): Observable<never> {
    let errorMessage: string;
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      errorMessage = `'${err.status} ${err.statusText}' when accessing '${err.url}'`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `an unknown error occurred ${err}`;
    }
    console.error(err);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Can Anyone please help me? I have been stuck on this for days now.
Thank you!

Comment: From your title it seems like you know what the problem is no? dieren$ in your *ngFor needs to be an iterable eg an array. I can't really tell what's going on but it looks like dieren$ is an observable?

Comment: Usually, when using `*ngFor` with an observable, you use the `async` pipe. Like so: `*ngFor="let dier of dieren$ | async"`

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you so much! I'm still learning Angular so I didn't know. I used the let dier of (dieren$ | async) and now it works.

Comment: @R.Richards could you write this as a post so I can upvote and mark it as answered? Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `*ngFor` with an observable, you need to use the `async` pipe.

Like so: `*ngFor="let dier of dieren$ | async"`

[Async Pipe Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

From the docs:

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.